# Stackdriver monitoring for Cloud Functions with HTTP trigger

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, stackdriver

I would like to be notified when my Firebase Cloud Function fails. This would work normally in Stackdriver for "regular" database-triggerd functions, but my HTTP-triggered functions are not available in the list on stackdriver, see screenshot (upper part from Functions Dashboard, lower part from Stackdriver)

[image: Functions Dashboard x Stackdriver]

Is there any way to monitor HTTP-triggered Firebase Cloud Functions?

Comment: From stackdriver monitoring, have you tried with create alerting policy while selecting “Firebase Realtime DataBase” from target resource type and “HTTPS Requests received” from Configuration IF Metric section? You can monitor cloud functions matrices in the [Firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/monitored-metrics) and cloud console as well.